# JQuery Function Loop

Tags: jquery, function, loops

I am trying to make it so my websites background changes colour randomly every few seconds. I can get it to change to a random colour but how do I make it loop?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';  

    function colourSet(){
       $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: hue}, 2000);
    }   

    colourSet();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it loop simply by having the function register *itself* as its own completion handler:

```
function colourSet() {
   var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')'; 
   $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: hue}, 2000, colourSet);
}
```

NB: the hue has to be picked inside the function otherwise it'll remain the same colour every time.

Just for fun, you can also make the hue code slightly shorter using some Javascript hacks (ahem):

```
function r() { return ~~(256 * Math.random()) };
function colourSet() {
   var hue = 'rgb(' + [r(), r(), r()] + ')';
   $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: hue}, 2000, colourSet);
}
```

which takes advantage of two uses of the bitwise `~` ("not") operator to convert floating point to integer, and also because concatenating an array to a string automatically does a `.toString()` on the array - resulting in a comma separated list.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `setInterval`. See below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function () {
       var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';  
       colourSet(hue);
    }, 30000); //30 seconds

    function colourSet(hue){
       $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: hue}, 2000);
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function(){
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';  

        function colourSet(){
           $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: hue}, 2000);
        }   

        colourSet();
    },60000 /* 60 seconds */);
});
</script>
```